# When do you use ‘some of which’ and ‘some of them’ and what is the correct punctuation?

Tags: sentence-construction, exam-questions

> Universities have historically offered a wide variety of continuing education **classes, some of ______ are** now offered over the Internet as well as in traditional classrooms.

The choices are:

1. classes, some of them that are
2. classes. some of which are
3. class, some of which are

The answer is (3) can you tell me why?

Comment: Is this from a workbook or a homework assignment?  All of them look awkward at best, including #3.

Comment: Also, did you copy #3 correctly? Shouldn’t it be “classes” instead of “class”.

Comment: If it's all one sentence, it's **classes, some of which are**. If it's two sentences, **classes. Some of them are**.